# Postgres DB URL string from a K8s deployment yaml file

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I am trying to contact from a customized helm chart to a fully managed Postgres service on azure, and then I have to put the url connection string according to the app I want to deploy.

I want to ask which value should be the `DATABASE_URL` at the helm chart deployment?
My situation is the following:

- I want to use an external Azure managed PostgreSQL and no the PostgreSQL container that comes with the helm chart.
  So in consequence, I modified the `DATABASE_URL` value, [given here](https://github.com/pivotal/postfacto/blob/master/deployment/helm/templates/deployment.yaml#L72-L73) to connect to the container inside K8s, I've modified in this way:

```
 name: DATABASE_URL
 # value: "postgres://{{ .Values.postgresql.postgresqlUsername }}:$(POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD)@{{ .Release.Name }}-postgresql"
 value: "postgres://nmbrs@postgresql-nmb-psfc-stag:$(POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD)@postgresql-nmb-psfc-stag.postgres.database.azure.com/postfacto-staging-db"
```

but I am getting this error

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/uri/generic.rb:208:in `initialize': the scheme postgres does not accept registry part: nmbrs@postgresql-nmb-psfc-stag:mypassword*@postgresql-nmb-psfc-stag.postgres.database.azure.com (or bad hostname?) (URI::InvalidURIError)
```

Which should be the real `DATABASE_URL` value if I want to contact to a fully Postgres managed service?

Which is the equivalent value to this?:

```
value: "postgres://{{ .Values.postgresql.postgresqlUsername }}:$(POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD)@{{ .Release.Name }}-postgresql"
```

I mean is

```
postgres//<username>:<my-pg-password>@<WHICH VALUE SHOULD BE HERE?>
```

What is the value of `{{ .Release.Name }}-postgresql"` ?

Just for the record, my customize `postfacto/deployment/helm/templates/deployment.yaml` is [this](https://gist.github.com/bgarcial/22ac1722a778cc17cc57f05a20e46ad1)

**UPDATE**

I changed the value for this

```
- name: DATABASE_URL
            # value: "postgres://{{ .Values.postgresql.postgresqlUsername }}:$(POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD)@{{ .Release.Name }}-postgresql"
            # value: "postgres://nmbrs@postgresql-nmb-psfc-stag:$(POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD)@postgresql-nmb-psfc-stag.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/postfacto-staging-db"
            value: "postgres://postgresql-nmb-psfc-stag.postgres.database.azure.com/postfacto-staging-db"
```

And I got a different error:

```
Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Invalid Username specified. Please check the Username and retry connection. The Username should be in <username@hostname> format.
FATAL:  Invalid Username specified. Please check the Username and retry connection. The Username should be in <username@hostname> format.
```

But is not clear how should be the syntax format since [this article](https://medium.com/avmconsulting-blog/how-to-deploy-rails-application-to-kubernetes-da8f23d45c6b) says:

> Next, encode the database credentials. Use the format DB_ADAPTER://USER:PASSWORD@HOSTNAME/DB_NAME. If you are using mysql with a user ‘deploy’ and a password ‘secret’ on 127.0.0.1 and have a database railsapp, run

The format `DB_ADAPTER://USER:PASSWORD@HOSTNAME/DB_NAME`, it is the same I was using at the beginning

Comment: `value: "postgres://nmbrs:$(POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD)@postgresql-nmb-psfc-stag.postgres.database.azure.com/postfacto-staging-db"` - why is the database name added to the username/password segment

Comment: Yes the database name is not intended to be there, [if we see the url defined in the helm chart](https://github.com/pivotal/postfacto/blob/master/deployment/helm/templates/deployment.yaml#L72-L73)  I was just trying a different format. 
In anyway if I remove the database name at the end, the error is the same.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I think rails as a fremework has a specific way to define the database url connection, I am checking this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database but not clear for me

Comment: what is the error after the change? also, what is `test2021*`? is it the password

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes that is a test passwd sorry, can you see my update above in the question please?

Comment: try `postgres://nmbrs%40postgresql-nmb-psfc-stag:$(POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD)@postgresql-nmb-psfc-stag.postgres.database.azure.com/postfacto-staging-db` - it uses a URL encoded value for the username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem with your connection string is, its *username* has a special character `@`, which might be breaking the connection string format and causing the validation error.

Your value

```
- name: DATABASE_URL
  value: "postgres://nmbrs@postgresql-nmb-psfc-stag:$(POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD)@postgresql-nmb-psfc-stag.postgres.database.azure.com/postfacto-staging-db"
```

You can try to do an URL encoding for the *username* part like

```
- name: DATABASE_URL
  value: "postgres://nmbrs%40postgresql-nmb-psfc-stag:$(POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD)@postgresql-nmb-psfc-stag.postgres.database.azure.com/postfacto-staging-db"
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see this helm chart is poorly written, and badly assumes things i.e. the DATABASE_URL has is build to only properly format a kubernetes posgress helm release and nothing else.

What I would suggest:

1. Instead of installing this chart on k8s by helm, use `helm template` functionality to locally render the template.
2. Edit the exported plain manifest, to match your needs
3. Go to your Azure DB, and get it `ConnectionString`, depending on how you mange your secrets in k8s, pass it to the `DATABASE_URL` environment
4. Manually apply the manifests

Comment: I see I will think about this. Thanks